# What is the equivalent of emacs's fill-paragraph in MacVim?

Tags: vim, text-editor, macvim

I'm familiar with solutions that will automatically wrap to 80 characters, etc.  But `fill-paragraph` lets me wrap things to 80 characters (or whatever) when I want to, which is convenient.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm not familiar with emacs or its fill-paragraph, but it sounds like you're looking for `gq`. It takes a movement, so either highlight what you want to wrap or use a movement command. E.g. `gggqG` will wrap the entire buffer.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is the `formatoptions` option, which configures how the formatting will happen.  See ':help fo' and ':help fo-table'.

Comment: "It takes a movement" - it also applies to a selection. Select with `v` or `V`, then `gq`, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about your cursor staying put, then use `gwip`.

The `gw` command has the form `gw{motion}`.  The `gw` command formats the lines that `{motion}` moves over and puts the cursor back at the same position in the text.  The motion `ip` stands for 'inner paragraph'.  You can think of the command as saying "format the paragraph I am in".

To define the fill width to 80 characters, you would want to do either

```
:set textwidth=80
```

or

```
:set tw=80
```

The `textwidth` variable defines the maximum width of text that is being inserted.  Lines longer than this width are broken after the white space.  Note that `textwidth` is not available in `vi`.

Note, it's likely that Vim and Emacs have different definitions for what constitutes a paragraph.  If you care about that level of detail, you can always read more about the various commands using `:help gw`, `:help ip`, `:help tw`, etc.